# How to set proper values for TThread Policy and Priority in Delphi 10.3 and Linux64 Compiler

Tags: linux, delphi, thread-priority, delphi-10.3-rio

Within my Delphi Linux application I like to set a thread priority to "tpTimeCritical". Unfortunately the priority value cannot be changed. Every value <> 0 throws a Runtime Error 217.

I found out that on Linux the policy has to be changed first (SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR). In sched.h I have the following values:

```
#define SCHED_NORMAL    0
#define SCHED_FIFO      1
#define SCHED_RR        2
#define SCHED_BATCH     3
#define SCHED_IDLE      5
#define SCHED_DEADLINE  6
```

After the policy has been set correctly, the priority should be set to a value between 1 and 99. Unfortunately this does not work.

```
constructor TMyThread.Create;
begin
   inherited Create(True);

   Policy   := 1;
   Priority := 90;
end;
```

Comment: Is this something that is even exposed by the Delphi `TThread` wrapper? Don't you need to call the pthreads functions directly? I don't see evidence that there is a property named `Policy`, and `Priority` exists but is typed as a `TThreadPriority` and is clearly Windows only. Where did the code in the question come from? Is it based on documentation, or reading the source code for `TThread`?

Comment: See System.Classes, TThread Class `{$ELSEIF Defined(POSIX)}
    // ** Priority is an Integer **
    property Priority: Integer read GetPriority write SetPriority;
    property Policy: Integer read GetPolicy write SetPolicy;
{$ENDIF POSIX}`

Comment: OK, I guess my mistake was reading the documentation!! Can you see where in the code that these property values are used?

Comment: In the POSIX GetPriority getter there is the information "SCHED_RR and SCHED_FIFO can only be set by root." The PAServer runs with sudo... and I also tested with root login. Same result: Runtime Error 217.

Comment: SchedTypes.inc: `{
 * POSIX scheduling policies
}
  SCHED_OTHER = 0;
  {$EXTERNALSYM SCHED_OTHER}
  SCHED_FIFO = 1;
  {$EXTERNALSYM SCHED_FIFO}
  SCHED_RR = 2;
  {$EXTERNALSYM SCHED_RR}`

Comment: Any ideas? Maybe the best option would be a support call @ Embarcadero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my inquiry about this with Embarcadero (RSP-26280) it turned out to be a bug in the corresponding Linux thread implementation. The bug was fixed in June 2020 and the fix was included in the next official release (I think 10.4).